# Robot Framework's Evaluate returns encoding error

Tags: python, encoding, robotframework

I am using the **Evaluate** keyword to create an array of arrays as follows :

```
${ARRAY}=   Evaluate    [['one', 'two', 'thrée']]
```

The porblem is that after the evaluation by **python 2** the variable `${ARRAY}` contains :

```
INFO : ${ARRAY} = [['one', 'two', 'thr\xc3\xa9e']]
```

**The problem is that the 'é' became \xc3\xa9.**

The encoding used in my IDE is UTF-8 so I'm guessing it's related to the default encoding used by python.
I get this when running the following script to check used encoding in python :

```
cmd > python
 Python 2.7.18 ... [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
 >>> import sys;
 >>> print(sys.stdin.encoding, sys.stdout.encoding)
 ('cp850', 'cp850')
 >>> print(sys.getdefaultencoding())
 ascii
```

So I was wondering what can I do to fix this problem? Most answers I found were related to in script changes not for something that is initiated by a call from Robot Framework.

Comment: You mention python **2**. Have you tried doing this with python 3?

Comment: No I haven't tried that yet

Comment: Upgrading to python 3 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to python 3 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not having a py2 at hand to try, what about if you initialize the variable explicitly as unicode:

```
${ARRAY}=   Evaluate    [['one', 'two', u'thrée']]
```